# How to turn off the switch button in Activity B by enabling switch button in activity A?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in my application. Let's say Activity A and Activity B. How can I turn off the switch button in Activity B by enabling the switch button in Activity A and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

By implementing interface between the two activities when the switch off an activity A fire the interface in Activity B